# Compiling typescript in Visual Studio gives error "Unexpected Token..."

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am working on a large complex node project in Visual Studio 2013 update 5.  I have tsc version 1.8.5 installed, and cannot find any references on my system to any other version.  When I compile on the commandline using "tsc --module commonjs", the program compiles cleanly.

When I compile in visual studio I get the error

```
Build: Unexpected token; 'module, class, interface, enum, import or statement expected'
```

The file flagged is express.d.ts.

This is stopping me from running the debugger, even though I can compile on the commandline.  Is there something about VS configured incorrectly?

James

Answer (score 0):

Given the commandline that works, I'm betting you need to modify your *tsconfg.json*

The import bits down there is obviously the `"module": "commonjs"`

This is an entire "standard" tsconfig file for use with Typings v1.0.0 or greater.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index.d.ts",
    "typings/modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Comment: "module": "commonjs" is already there.  I attempted adding some exclusions but still could not get it to work.  Any other important bits I might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and select "Properties". In the Typescript tab, select the correct module system (this will add the correct compiler flags)

Comment: CommonJS is selected.  Is that not the correct module?

Comment: When I encountered this problem, this is how I was able to fixed it (although I use AMD rather than CommonJS)

Comment: AMD gives me the same result.  I cannot say I really understand what these modules are.